# C# Input Delegate Requirements

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I am trying to better understand how one understands the requirements of a delegate function parameter to a function. In other words, how does one know which operations need to be performed in the delegate?

For example, [HostBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostbuilder.configureappconfiguration?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) takes as input a *configureDelegate*.

How do we know what to do within the expression provided as input such as below:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Host.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
{
    config.AddJsonFile("MySubsection.json",
                       optional: true,
                       reloadOnChange: true);
});

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();
```

Comment: In the case of these builders, I'd look at the documentation for what they're supposed to before. What you can do is also informed by what the delegate's arguments are, so we se we have `hostingContext` and `config` so we know we can do something with these. You can look up the documentation for them too. Do you have a more targeted question?

Comment: You need a nice guy to populate some examples in the documentation just like [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find?view=net-6.0#examples). If you are at leisure now, you can edit the page and add your code.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will help you to understand the concept, for more detail visit [Action delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=net-6.0)

```
public void ConfigureAppConfiguration(Action<HostingContext,Config> configuration) {

 var configData = configuration();

 //Further process 

}


// how it invoke  
ConfigureAppConfiguration((context,config)=> {

config.AddJsonFile("MySubsection.json",
                       optional: true,
                       reloadOnChange: true);

});
```